# How to set current directory in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and using a Windows PC. I am trying to set up my GHCi interface so that I can write my code in my text editor before executing it using the GHCi.

Currently, my GHCi reads

```
$ ghci GHCi, version 6.12.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/ :? for help 
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done. 
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done. 
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude>
```

According to this [site](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html), I have to save my Haskell files to the current directory or specify some other directory in order to access them. This is what I don't know how to do.

**My Questions:**

1. How do I set the current directory?
2. How do I get the GHCi to tell me what the path for current directory is so I can check what it is set at when I want to?

Please explain starting from the line

```
Prelude>
```

as noted above so that I can follow along.

**Note:**

The example Haskell code given was

file name: Main.hs

```
main = print(fac(20))

fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac(n-1)
```

and in the GHCi

```
prelude> :load Main 
Compiling Main ( Main.hs, interpreted ) 
Ok, modules loaded: Main. 
*Main> fac 17 
355687428096000
```

So I want to save Main.hs to a directory, specify this as the current directory in the GHCi, and then run the above code.

Comment: How are you launching `ghci`?  Are you running `ghci` from the command line or some other method?

Comment: There is a link in my start menu that I click. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I don't use Windows, but `:!cd` should give you the current directory, and `:cd <dir>` should change directory to `<dir>`.

Comment: If you're using stack, you could simply run `stack ghci`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> How do I set the current directory?

GHCi provides the `:cd <dir>` command. You can get the list of all commands with `:?`. If you omit the directory, you will change to your home again.

> How do I get the GHCi to tell me what the path for current directory is so I can check what it is set at when I want to?

Funny enough, GHCi doesn't provide a command for this, but you can use Window's `cd` command. In order to execute an external command, you need to use `:!`, e.g. `:! cd`.

#### Example

```
ghci> :! cd
C:\Users\Zeta
ghci> :cd workspace
ghci> :cd stackoverflow
ghci> :! cd
C:\Users\Zeta\workspace\stackoverflow
ghci> :cd
ghci> :!cd
C:\Users\Zeta
```

Comment: “If you omit the directory, you will change to your home again.” ← This is actually POSIX standard behavior of `cd`, if `$HOME` is set, and so, implied by `cd`, even in GHCi. :) (If `$HOME` is unset, the behavior is undefined. `bash` does just show an error that the variable is not set.)

Comment: And all of that works in exactly the same way on a Mac: Prelude>:! ls will get the contents. Prelude>:! cd <YourChosenPath> etc.

Answer (score 2):

well just answer is `:cd`  as @Zeta wroted
but futher more, for searching someone like me

- path: `:cd`
- path with command: `:! cd` just like vim `!` is  of user's OS console
- `:cd <DIR>` is almost equor `:! cd <DIR>`
- there's another way `:show paths` that shows somepaths, and there's current dicectory

PS> Searched some conf.d(~/.ghci/ghci.conf) like one but failed.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in Windows 10 with GHCi-8.10.4 is

```
:cd c:\\Work\Finance\UT Trial Balance
```

And

```
:cd ..
```

Works well, too. One assumes Haskell strings [Char] but no, literal strings. The spaces do not even have to be escaped. The Windows backward slash works, too. ugh.
You still have to use

```
:! cd
```

to see where you are. I am assumming, now I can `:l` my code in my working directory.

If you go out with like `:! bash -i` it is a fork and separate. You can cd all over but it will not change the GHCi working directory.

And `:! pwd` works in my GHCi.

Now you get very many Linux tools when you install Haskell-dev. It's sweet. I got rid of Cygwin and installed **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS** in windows last year which is real Linux on Windows but the commands are not available at the Windows command line. Now, with Haskell-dev I get Linux everywhere for free. Joy.